# UITableView custom cell disappears and appears randomly while scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

Good Evening

I have a UITableView with custom cells, which behaves weird and I can't find the solution. So my table points to the controller and uses it as dataSource. Here is the code to retrieve cells

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let tempCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(armPointCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AircraftTableCell

    tempCell.hidden = false
    tempCell.UILabel_aircraftName.text = "CELL #\(indexPath.row) : \(tempCell)"

    print("\(indexPath.row): \(tempCell)")

    return tempCell;

}
```

When I scroll, cells appear and disapper. I never get nils in the print-out. Here is before scrolling up and down:

[image: Before Scrolling]

And here is after

[image: After Scrolling]

I tried googling, but nothing helps...

**Update 1**

So I tried debugging based in suggestion that the items get 0 height, or get moved under other items. But I actually have empty views for some cells. Here is sample debug output. You can see that one cell has switch and label, and the other doesn't. I hope somebody knows what to do :((

[image]

Comment: What is the `TITLE`? I see it change height. Is it a UITableViewCell?

Comment: IIRC there is something about the cell being partially or fully visible in the tableview which is causing the first cell not to have a cell index as a visible cell.

Comment: Title is different size because I moved the list. It's just a section title. I'll try to print out heights and visibilities of all cells, but so far I have no changes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody stumbles upon that issue. If your ViewController (that has TableView) inside it is a UITabBarController and you are having this issue, there is a temp work-around: Embed your ViewController inside NavigationController. This issue happens only when ViewController is embedded in TabBarController. Like on this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
let tempCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(armPointCellIdentifier) as! AircraftTableCell
```

Hope it works! Another solution is to set default values to your cell labels before give them the input of your array.

Comment: Tried it, didn't help :(